# Android, how to define onAttachedToWindow() method?

Tags: android

I am using gradient as background in my activity. on some android devices it doesn't look as good and smooth as in Photoshop, to fix this issue somebody told me use `onAttachedToWindow()` method.

I checked Android page ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onAttachedToWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29)) and I found that this method is a part of `android.app.Activity`and I wrote following lines of code:

```
package com.test.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class Mainctivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() { 
        super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
        Window window = getWindow(); 
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888); 
    }
}
```

but when run the emulator, it crashed and in DDMS I saw this error:

```
11-25 10:48:13.353: E/dalvikvm(216): Could not find method android.app.Activity.onAttachedToWindow, referenced from method com.test.test1.MainActivity.onAttachedToWindow
```

What is my fault?

Comment: I've tried your code an it works fine for me. (GingerBread, Galaxy S2)

Comment: Thanks for your good news. I tested on a real device it works too. but i don't know why in emulator shows error?!!!

Comment: Yeah the emulator is not completely reliable. It needs a lot of work, for some tasks it's best to trust the actual device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments above, I've had this code tested on an actual device and it worked smoothly. So this is an emulator problem. Hopefully this will be resolved in later versions of the sdk.

Answer (score 3):

This method is available since API Level 5. What version of Android is running on the emulator?